# How to create a simple mouseover/mouseout action on a object javascript

Tags: javascript

For example a simple rectangle with text 'Hello World' to be displayed when mouseover:

```
<rect id="svg_1" height="100" width="165" y="101" x="136" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="88" x="221" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">Hello World</text>
```

Comment: <rect id="svg_1" height="100" width="165" y="101" x="136" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="88" x="221" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">Hello World</text>

Comment: This is the code i want to use, i want the text 'Hello World' to be displayed when the mouse is over the shape.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS:

```
text {
 visibility: hidden;
}

text :hover {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to show the text when the rectangle is hovered, as written this doesn't work since there's no text to hover over. If the text is always the next sibling of the rect `rect:hover + text {visibility: visible;}` is the one that will work.

Comment: " there's no text to hover over" heum nope, visibility just hide the text it's still "displayed"